# How to empirically identify trends exactly offseting each other?

Tags: regression, time-series, multicollinearity, trend, identifiability

Say a random variable $Y$ is affected by both $X$ and $Z$, in the following way (data generation process):

$$ y_t = a + bx_t + cz_t + \epsilon_t $$

where $\epsilon_t$ is a white noise.

Furthermore, say that, **in a given period for which data is available**, the behaviour of $X$ and $Z$ is such that

$$ x_t = -\frac{b}{c}z_t + \mu_t $$

where $\mu_t$ is a white noise. 
This is, in the observed period, these variables follow **opposite trends/behaviour**. Importantly, this is an empirical relation, contingent to the period observed, and need not to be theoretically true for the data generation process.

Given this relation, it is clear that the **observed behaviour** of $y_t$ is that of a white noise around a constant (just plug in one equation into the other and rearrange).

Since standard regression techniques require the dependent variable to have some variability, then it is clear that an OLS would fail to identify $x_t$ and $z_t$. This is, OLS cannot differentiate between a model with these variables and without them.

This means that, for a given period, we might think that $x_t$ and $z_t$ are irrelevant for $y_t$, even though they are.

The above could be extended to more variables. For instance, add a variable $w_t$ to the data generation process, systematically unrelated to $x_t$ and $z_t$. OLS will identify $w_t$ as significant but will not find the other two variables to be significant.

Is there an empirical method to check if two (or more) variables that mutually offset each other are relevant for a given process?

Comment: Good question. This has to do with how representative a sample is for the population (contrast *observed behaviour* with *unobserved behaviour*). If you want to model just this special period where the influences of $x_t$ and $z_t$ cancel out, then you do not need either of the variables and $y_t$ is just white noise. This holds *in population* as long as this special relationship between $x_t$ and $z_t$ persists. Now if the data generating process changes and $x_t$ is no longer proportional to $z_t$ in this specific way, their effects on $y_t$ do not cancel out and you can identify them.

Comment: In summary, if the sample is representative and you have multicollinearity, there is no way of identifying the effects individually (just the effect of the linear combination).

Comment: @RichardHardy Mmm, I see. So this is then an issue of multicolinearity. This is imo an interesting constraint of empirical analysis when it comes to understanding the determinants of phenomena. We never know if some linear combination of other factors are offsetting each other. This is quite relevant in economics, where human agency reacts to stuff. For instance, think of a country facing little inflation, not because there were no shocks, but because the central bank got very good at counteracting them. Empirically, you cannot tell the difference though. (thanks for the tags)

Comment: I agree. An interesting question (as I have already mentioned)!